# OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier show which markers are in a 'spiderfy cluster'?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map with a bunch of markers on it. Some of those markers have the same lat/lon as other markers, so sit on top of each other. I'm using the oms library to allow for the markers to be spiderfied out so each marker can be clicked.

All working great so far. However the only way you can tell if there's multiple markers is by clicking on the markers, which is a problem for my application.

**Is there a way to indicate which markers are grouped into 'spiderfy' clusters?**

I'm also using the MarkerClustererPlus library to handle clusters. It could be possible to use the clusterer library to provide a count and then 'on click' spiderify the markers but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

If you check [**this example**](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/example/marker-clustering-spiderfier.html) it has spiderfy and cluster plugins mixed and working smoothly. But my problem is I am using google map API with markercluster and [**OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier**](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) plugin. I was also looking for if we can use leaflet cluster plugin for google map? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Did you figure out how to implement this using Google maps?
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listener to check if the marker is spiderfiable or not. If it is spiderfiable, it means that there are others elements under that pin.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'spider_format', function(status) {   

        if(status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIED 
|| status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.UNSPIDERFIABLE)

        {
            marker.setIcon('Markers/marker.png'); 
//use a normal marker if the element is already spiderfied 
//or if it can not be spiderfied
        }

        if(status == OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.markerStatus.SPIDERFIABLE)

        {
            marker.setIcon('Markers/cluster_marker.png'); //use a different marker
        }           
    });
```